# passport-local-mongoose: No response

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

When authenticating with the server, the server does not respond to the POST request. The server recieves the requesst and parses the JSON correctly, but it never sends the response. I have followed many guides and updated Node to no avail.

The code is fairly straightforward, the relevant parts are:

**app.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var connectMongo = require('connect-mongo');
var debug = require('debug')('sess:app');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var index = require('./routes/index');
var home = require('./routes/home');
var about = require('./routes/about');
var catalog = require('./routes/catalog');
var branches = require('./routes/branches');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var dbconnect = require('./dbconnect');

var app = express();
var MongoStore = connectMongo(session);
var sessionConnect = dbconnect.Session;

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    name: '...',
    secret: '...',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    rolling: true,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: sessionConnect }),
    cookie: { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true, sameSite: true }
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// passport setup
var User = require('./models/user')(dbconnect.Models);
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

// Create user for testing
User.create({username:'admin',password:'12345',deleted:false,kind:'manager'});

// login
// This was attempted with additional redirection options as well
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
  // This message never appears in the log
  console.log('auth');
  res.status(200).end();
});

// logout
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err);
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**dbconnect.js:**

```
var mongo = require("mongoose");
mongo.Promise = global.Promise;
var debug = require('debug')('sess:app');

function dbconnect(path){
    var userConnStr = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/ise_' + path + '_v6';
    var db = mongo.createConnection()
    db.on('connecting', function() { debug('Connecting to MongoDB: '); });
    db.on('connected', function() { debug('Connected to MongoDB: '); });
    db.on('disconnecting', function() { debug('Disconnecting to MongoDB: '); });
    db.on('disconnected', function() { debug('Disconnected to MongoDB: '); });
    db.on('reconnected', function() { debug('Reconnected to MongoDB: '); });
    db.on('error', function(err) { debug('Error to MongoDB: ' + err); });
    db.on('open', function() { debug('MongoDB open : '); });
    db.on('close', function() { debug('MongoDB close: '); });
    process.on('SIGINT', function() { db.close(function () { process.exit(0); });});
    db.openUri(userConnStr);
    console.log('Pending DB connection');
    return db;
};

module.exports = {Session: dbconnect('session'), Models: dbconnect('models'), Custom: dbconnect};
```

**models/user.js:**

```
var mongo = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongo.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var userSchema = new Schema({ // create a schema
  name: { first: String, last: String }, // field-object (with sub-fields)
  kind: { type: String, required: true, enum: ["manager", "employee", "customer", "supplier"] },
  email: String,
  branch: Number,
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date,
  deleted: { type: Boolean, required: true }
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

userSchema.methods.remove = function() {
  deleted = true;
  save();
};

// on every save, add the date
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) { //callback
  // get the current date
  var currentDate = new Date();
  // change the updated_at field to current date
  this.updated_at = currentDate;
  // if created_at doesn't exist, add to that field
  if (!this.created_at)
    this.created_at = currentDate;
  next();
});

module.exports = function(db){
    return db.model('User', userSchema);
};
```

The client code uses AngularJS v1:

**Controller function:**

```
$scope.signin = function(){
        $http.post("login", {'username': $scope.username, 'password': $scope.password}).then(function(data){
            // ......
        }, function(data){
            alert("Wrong username or password");
        });
    };
```

**HTML Bootstrap modal:**

```
<div id="signInModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" >
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Sign in</h4>
      </div>
      <form>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input ng-model="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input ng-model="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="signin()">Sign in</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a similar issue (while testing with postman) and can't find what's wrong, have you ever found what was the issue @OronDF343 ?

Comment: OK, finally in my case I forgot to connect to mongoose in a specific case :)